# How to test if the result of netip.ParsePrefix() is IPv6 in Go?

Tags: go, ipv6, ipv4

How can I determine that the CIDR block parsed by `netip.ParsePrefix()` was in IPv4 or IPv6 format?

- With `net.ParseCIDR()` I could call `.To4()` and test for `nil`.
- Is4() is not defined for netip.Prefix.
- I considered using p.Bits() that that is ambiguous for Prefixes of len 32 or shorter.

```
        p, err := netip.ParsePrefix(cidr)
        p.Is4() // ERROR!  p.Is4 undefined (type netip.Prefix has no field or method Is4)
```

Answer (score 3):

Call `p.Addr()` to retrieve the prefix's IP address, then call `.Is4()` or `.Is6()` on the address.

For example: `p.Addr().Is6()`

Or a longer example:

```
        p, err := netip.ParsePrefix(cidr)
        fmt.Printf("p=%v ipv6=%v, err=%v\n", p, p.Addr().Is6(), err)
```